# Office Plugin Error 2709 "Offline join completion information was not found"

Tags: c#, excel, installshield, windows-10, excel-addins

I have an installer created with InstallShield LE for an Excel plugin that is failing on a Windows 10 tablet with Office 365 with the error *Error 2709 Offline join completion information was not found*. This has not occurred on any other install on Windows 7/8/8.1 and across both Office 2010 and 2013.

Upon googling I can see this is not an uncommon error and usually requires the removal of a couple of Windows updates (KB3008627 and KB2918614) however these are not present on the Windows 10 box in question.

So is this something unique to 365 (although I would be surprised) or something with Windows 10?

Comment: As an update a clean install of Windows 10 with Office 2013 (not 365) still results in this issue.

Comment: I never did find a solution to this, I gave up and used the Office Development Publish Wizard in Visual Studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625071.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error (different installation package) on a clean win 10 machine. 
I found this reg hack from IBM. Basically creating a white list of MSI IDs. After following the instructions, I was able to install the MSI without error. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI26638

Hope it helps others.

Here is the reg hack -

RESOLUTION: We followed these steps to fix the issue:

1. Click Start , click Run , type regedit in the Open box, and
   then click OK .
2. Locate and then click the following subkey in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer

If the above key does not exist, create it.

3. On the Edit menu, point to New , and then click DWORD Value .
4. Type SecureRepairPolicy for the name of the DWORD, and then
   press Enter.
5. Right-click SecureRepairPolicy , and then click Modify .
6. In the Value data box, type 2 , and then click OK .
7. Locate and then click the following subkey in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer

8. On the Edit menu, point to New , and then click Key .
9. Type SecureRepairWhitelist for the name of the key, and then
   press Enter.
10. Double-click the SecureRepairWhitelist key to open it.
11. On the Edit menu, point to New , and then click String Value
    . Create String Values that contain the product codes (including
    braces {}) of the products that have to be added to the Safe
    Recipients list.

NOTE:

The NAME of the String Value is the "product code" and the VALUE
can be left blank. To obtain the product code for other MSIs,
open the MSI by using the ORCA tool that is available in Windows
SDK.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.